# Is ingress filtering described in RFC2827 implemented in most routers? How does such implementation look like?

Tags: routing, router, openwrt, firmware, traffic-filtering

[RFC 2827](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc2827) describes the idea of ingress filtering that is meant to
deal with DOS attacks that utilize IP spoofing:

> An input traffic filter on the ingress (input) link of "router 2", which provides
> connectivity to the attacker's network, restricts traffic to allow
> only traffic originating from source addresses within the
> 204.69.207.0/24 prefix, and prohibits an attacker from using
> "invalid" source addresses which reside outside of this prefix range.

Is such filtering implemented in every router that firmware such as
openWRT supports? Would anybody be so kind and provide me with a relevant
snippet of code that provides for such filtering. Was there ever a documented
case of an attack that utilized IP spoofing along with a tweak in the firmware of the attacker's router that allowed for the lack of said filtering.

Comment: That RFC is a "Best Current Practice" not a "Standards Track" RFC. It is not a requirement in _[RFC 1812, Requirements for IP Version 4 Routers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1812.html)_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is such filtering implemented in every router that firmware such as openWRT supports?

Not every router supports [ACL](https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/definition/access-control-list-ACL)s. Many do, and to filter by source address a simple ACL is enough. You don't have to support stateful filtering, so it's cheap to implement. But there's no inherent requirement in IP that routers supports filtering.

As Drop traffic is commonly the default policy for a firewall, this can be achieved simply with a permit matching the desired source addresses. Traffic not matching that rule will be dropped by default policy if that is drop.